# spring security authorized urls do not enter my AbstractSecurityInterceptor filter

Tags: spring-security

I am just using spring-security to authorization the url resource depend on the user related roles , but my login in is not rely on spring-security.
But my authorized urls do not enter the my  JWTAuthenticationFilter which is used to authorize the url.I don't know where is problem in my code ,please checkout the code below and point out the problem in my configuration or JWTAuthenticationFilter , that will be very helpful.
Or any related reference link also will be very appreciated. Thank you so much!

my configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST,
                        "/user/login",
                        "/user/sso/login")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/pos/findAllList")
                .authenticated().and()
                .addFilterBefore(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(),
                        FilterSecurityInterceptor.class)
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        super.configure(web);
        web
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers("/admin/swagger/**");

    }

}
```

my JWTAuthenticationFilter:

```
@Log4j2
public class JWTAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractSecurityInterceptor implements Filter{
    @Autowired
    private FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource;
    @Autowired
    private SmcAccessDecisionManager smcAccessDecisionManager;

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {
        super.setAccessDecisionManager(smcAccessDecisionManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("进入SmcSecurityFilter");
        FilterInvocation fi = new FilterInvocation( request, response, chain );
        invoke(fi);

    }

    public void invoke( FilterInvocation object ) throws IOException, ServletException{
        super.beforeInvocation(object);
        Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes = securityMetadataSource.getAttributes(object);
        this.smcAccessDecisionManager.decide(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(), object, attributes);
        InterceptorStatusToken token = super.beforeInvocation(object);
        try{
            object.getChain().doFilter(object.getRequest(), object.getResponse());
        }finally{
            super.afterInvocation(token, null);
        }

    }

    public FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource getSecurityMetadataSource(){
        return this.securityMetadataSource;
    }

    public void setSecurityMetadataSource(FilterInvocationSecurityMetadataSource securityMetadataSource) {
        this.securityMetadataSource = securityMetadataSource;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getSecureObjectClass() {
        return FilterInvocation.class;
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityMetadataSource obtainSecurityMetadataSource() {
        return this.securityMetadataSource;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your doFilter() to look like this:

```
@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    log.info("进入SmcSecurityFilter");
    FilterInvocation fi = new FilterInvocation( request, response, chain );
    invoke(fi, chain, request, response);
}
```

And your invoke() method like this:

```
  public void invoke(FilterInvocation object,  FilterChain chain, ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException{
    super.beforeInvocation(object);
    Collection<ConfigAttribute> attributes = securityMetadataSource.getAttributes(object);
    this.smcAccessDecisionManager.decide(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication(), object, attributes);
    InterceptorStatusToken token = super.beforeInvocation(object);
    try{
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }finally{
        super.afterInvocation(token, null);
    }

}
```